# How to properly feed a multi image input to a multi input cnn model in tensorflow keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to feed 4 different images to a multi input CNN.

This is how I load images:

```py
data_root = pathlib.Path('dataset/')
all_image_paths = list(data_root.glob('*/*'))
all_image_paths = [str(path) for path in all_image_paths]
image_count = len(all_image_paths)    
size = 300
def load_and_preprocess_image(path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image,3)
    # image = tf.image.central_crop(image, 0.8)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [size, size])
    image /= 255.0  # normalize to [0,1] range
    return image

trainA = []
trainB = []
trainC = []
trainD = []

testA = []
testB = []
testC = []
testD = []

i = 0
while i < 140:
    trainA.append(load_and_preprocess_image(all_image_paths[i]))
    trainB.append(load_and_preprocess_image(all_image_paths[i + 1]))
    trainC.append(load_and_preprocess_image(all_image_paths[i + 2]))
    trainD.append(load_and_preprocess_image(all_image_paths[i + 3]))
    i = i+4

while i < 160:
    testA.append(load_and_preprocess_image(all_image_paths[i]))
    testB.append(load_and_preprocess_image(all_image_paths[i + 1]))
    testC.append(load_and_preprocess_image(all_image_paths[i + 2]))
    testD.append(load_and_preprocess_image(all_image_paths[i + 3]))
    i = i+4
```

And this is how I load values for each bucket of 4 images from a csv file:

```py
import csv

values = []

with open('dataset/agrumeto.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        values.append(', '.join(row))

kilo_train = values[:35]
kilo_test = values[35:]
```

I defined my model as follows:

```py
def create_conv_layer(input):
    # the first branch operates on the first input
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (7, 7), activation='relu')(input)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), (2,2))(x)
    x = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)
    return x

# define two sets of inputs
inputA = tf.keras.Input(shape=(size,size,3))
inputB = tf.keras.Input(shape=(size,size,3))
inputC = tf.keras.Input(shape=(size,size,3))
inputD = tf.keras.Input(shape=(size,size,3))


x = create_conv_layer(inputA)
y = create_conv_layer(inputB)
w = create_conv_layer(inputC)
z = create_conv_layer(inputD)

# combine the output of the two branches
combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x.output, y.output, w.output, z.output])
layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu")(combined)
layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(layer_1)
layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation="relu")(layer_1)
layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), (2,2))(layer_2)
layer_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu")(layer_2)
layer_3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), (2,2))(layer_3)
layer_4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation="relu")(layer_3)
layer_4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), (2,2))(layer_4)
flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(layer_4)
hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(flatten)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(hidden1)


model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input, w.input, z.input], outputs=output)

# print(model.summary())
```

I try to run the model using the following code:

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mean_absolute_percentage_error")

print("[INFO] training model...")

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        (tf.stack(trainA), tf.stack(trainB),tf.stack(trainC), tf.stack(trainD)) )

output_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(kilo_train)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset, output_set))

model.fit(dataset,  epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=10, verbose=1)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate([testA, testB, testC, testD], kilo_test)

print(test_acc)
```

But I get the following error:

```sh
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4
> dimensions, but got array with shape (300, 300, 3)
```

I am using tf.stack in order to obtain a a single tensor for each batch of images:

```sh
<tf.Tensor: id=3439, shape=(35, 300, 300, 3)

without tf.stack, I get the following data structure:

<tf.Tensor: id=10, shape=(300, 300, 3) ( followed by more tensors )
```

Which is basically a list of tensors

If I don't use tf.stack I still get the same error. If I modify the dataset to:

```sh
> dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices( [
>     trainA, trainB,trainC, trainD])
```

I get another error:

```sh
> Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are
> passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to
> see 4 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:
> [<tf.Tensor: id=3850, shape=(35, 300, 300, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
```

But even if I pass a tuple of 4 arrays, I still get that error, even if using tf.stack makes the tensors 4 dimensional! WHat am I missing?

Comment: This seems an interesting question that is worth solving. However, your question is way too concrete, it depends too much on your particular example. I suggest you compress the code to its minima expression so that you can reproduce the error. This way you generalize the question and at the same time encourage other people to answer it and use it in the future.

Comment: How can I compress the code further? It's at its minimum already I believe. I could upload the whole file, it's about 100 lines of code

Comment: Can you give the result of `print(dataset.output_shapes)`?

Comment: @PierangeloCalanna Were you able to solve this problem? I am also struggling to implement a multi-input model